# Python selecting multiple ranges with numpy\pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, range

Is there anyway to select multiple ranges in numpy arrays or pandas dataframe efficiently all in one go?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import time

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10)))

%timeit -n 10000 result = pd.concat((data[100:150], data[200:300]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 1.47 ms per loop
```

In the above example, how can I select from 100 to 150 and 200:300 without using concat? Is this even possible?

The above operation, has a bottleneck when using pd.concat and can eventually been speed up using np.vstack...but still I'd like to select the two ranges all at once without copy the underling data as concat would do.

TIME is crucial, as I'd like to get as closer as possible as the time you'll get if you access directly to the continuos range as below:

```
%timeit -n 10000  result = data[100:150]
10000 loops, best of 3: 94 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches I can think of.  We can try them and see which is fastest.  However, you aren't going to be able to avoid a copy.  There is no way to handle discontinuous ranges without a copy.

**concat**

```
>>> %%timeit -n 10000  data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10)))
... result = pd.concat((data[100:150], data[200:300]))
...
10000 loops, best of 3: 3.81 ms per loop
```

**List of indexes**

```
>>> %%timeit -n 10000  data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10)))
... result = data.iloc[list(range(100, 150))+list(range(200, 300))]
...
10000 loops, best of 3: 479 µs per loop
```

**Logical indexing:**

```
>>> %%timeit -n 10000  data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10)))
... result = data[((100 <= data.index) & (data.index < 150)) | 
...               ((200 <= data.index) & (data.index < 300))]
...
10000 loops, best of 3: 580 µs per loop
```

**slice and drop**

```
>>> %%timeit -n 10000  data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.sample((10000,10)))
... result = data[100:300].drop(np.arange(150, 200))
...
10000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop
```

So it seems like providing a list of indexes or logical indexing are the fastest, with roughly equivalent speed (I wouldn't put any weight on a speed difference that small).

Comment: Why are you including creation of the data in your `timeit` loop?

Comment: When using `%%timeit`, the code on the `%%timeit` line is considered setup code and is not counted in the timing.  I do it this way to make sure that the data is re-generated each repeat.   `pandas` and/or `numpy` does some caching that screws up the timing if I don't do it this way.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: thanks for extensive comment! So there is no way to get any close to the time you'll get if you access directly to a continuos range? I've edited my answer to include the timing of (%timeit -n 10000  x = data[100:150]; 10000 loops, best of 3: 94 µs per loop) as the indentation in the comment is orrible

Comment: @AlessandroMariani  I am afraid not. You can think of numpy arrays (which pandas uses) as a contiguous block of memory, with the `nth` element `n` being in the `nth` region of memory in that black (technically it only has to be strided).  The algorithms that numpy uses for fast computation require this.  A slice is just a "view" into a part of that memory block without having to copy anything.  But in order for it to work like an array it still has to be contiguous.  If you want to use non-contiguous pieces, these need to be copied to a new contiguous block of memory, which is slow.

Comment: I see, the alternative would be use boolean indexing which apparently is slower than using list of indexing... and probably would also depends on how many rows are selected. thanks!

Comment: As I said, I wouldn't put any credence in the difference between the list and boolean indexing.  The timings depend a large part on what is going on in the computer at the time so they jump around quite a bit.  They are essentially the same speed within the margin of error of the test.  The memory copy is going to be the big performance penalty, and it will be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine boolean conditions, and pass them to the subscript operator:

```
data[((100 <= data.index) & (data.index < 150)) | ((200 <= data.index) & (data.index < 300))]
```

(Note the parentheses, BTW - they are unseemly, but the order of precedence requires them.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first need to make a list of the target rows and then use `iloc`.

```
rows = [i for i in list(range(100, 150)) + list(range(200, 250))]
>>> data.iloc[rows, :]
            0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
100  0.936412  0.875215  0.626169  0.362366  0.086108  0.709103  0.748132  0.696450  0.814539  0.502694
101  0.011131  0.733182  0.127739  0.743762  0.954454  0.018809  0.119522  0.319173  0.546778  0.982340
102  0.412659  0.977685  0.981917  0.319247  0.626653  0.845410  0.828058  0.506033  0.283324  0.495679
..        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
247  0.827967  0.803476  0.637800  0.603473  0.968779  0.976671  0.747728  0.029828  0.391113  0.381155
248  0.394331  0.120555  0.875771  0.529207  0.143756  0.334991  0.989489  0.584157  0.730615  0.187992
249  0.634841  0.624685  0.746429  0.374769  0.632195  0.922843  0.200508  0.024452  0.223971  0.457757

[100 rows x 10 columns]

%timeit rows = [i for i in list(range(100, 150)) + list(range(200, 300))]; data.iloc[rows, :]
1000 loops, best of 3: 283 µs per loop

%timeit pd.concat([data[100:150], data[200:300]])
1000 loops, best of 3: 927 µs per loop
```

Comment: 1. Some of your comprehensions are redunant: it's just `range(100, 150) + range(200, 250)` (shorter too). 2. IINM, you're moving from pandas speeds to Python speeds with what you wrote.

Comment: @AmiTavory Thanks.  I didn't know one could add ranges like that.

Comment: @AmiTavory You can't add ranges like that in Python 3.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Thanks. So in Py3 it would be `list(range(...)) + list(range(...))`?

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes, although that will work equally well in Python 2 and Python 3.  I try to write my code as generically as possible.